# Create QBPrivateChatManager getting error nullpointer in android

Tags: quickblox

create Quickblox chat but createdialog time geting nullpointer.

```
QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
            privateChatManager.createDialog(sub_arr.get(position).getOccupentId(), new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
                     Log.d("dialog1", dialog+"");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't call

```
QBChatService.getInstance().login(qbUser);
```

then next line will be returning null:

```
QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
```

So the right way is to login to chat and then obtain QBPrivateChatManager